# Append loop output in column pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with the code below to append output to empty dataframe

```
image_data = pd.DataFrame()

for i in words:
    y = re.findall('{} ([^ ]*)'.format(re.escape(i)), data)
    x = y
    image_data = image_data.append(x, ignore_index = True)
```

i am getting output as below but i want

```
        0
0   30708
1      15
2    1800
0   19200
1      50
2    1180
```

What i want the output to be

```
        0    1       2
0   30708   15    1800
1   19200   50    1180
```

How can i make 3 rows to  3 columns every time the loop repeats.

Comment: What is x exactly? What is its format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It perplexes me when you write `x = y` without doing any manipulation on `x`. Seems like a redundant operation. Another problem with your code is that `image_data.append` is slow since it has to copy the backing memory. Repeatedly calling it in a loop is a guarantee of performance bottleneck.

Try this instead:

```
# image_data starts as a list
image_data = []

for i in words:
    y = re.findall('{} ([^ ]*)'.format(re.escape(i)), data)
    image_data.append(y)

# And it ends as a DataFrame
image_data = pd.DataFrame(image_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

If `x` is a list of values, use:

```
image_data = image_data.append([x], ignore_index = True)
```

to append all the values as a new row instead of appending a single element as a row.
Look [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) for more details about the append method.

Answer (score 1):

```
# replicating your dataframe
data = [30708, 15, 1800, 19200, 50, 1180]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

you could first convert to numpy.ndarry in order to perform reshape():

```
vals = df[0].values.reshape(2, 3)
```

then back to pd.DataFrame if you really need it to be a pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(vals)
```